# How to make an item of eclipse context menu visible for certain extensions?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

I'm make an eclipse plugin that adds an item to eclipse project explorer context menu. I want to make this item visible for certain extensions.

I used the code below but it didn't work.

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
         <menu
               label="Sample Menu"
               mnemonic="M"
               id="TTT.menus.sampleMenu">
            <command
                  commandId="TTT.commands.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S"
                  id="TTT.menus.sampleCommand">

            <visibleWhen>
                <iterate operator="and" ifEmpty="false">
                   <test 
                          property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" 
                          value="*.h" />
                </iterate>
            </visibleWhen>

            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>


      <menuContribution
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
         <toolbar
               id="TTT.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
            <command
                  commandId="TTT.commands.sampleCommand"
                  icon="icons/sample.gif"
                  tooltip="Say hello world"
                  id="TTT.toolbars.sampleCommand">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Comment: This looks OK provided you are using it in an appropriate extension. Edit your question and show us the **full** `<extension> ... </extension>`, not just this extract.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 for your answer. I edited the question with the full code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching it worked when I added

```
<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
```

to the code to be as follows:

```
<visibleWhen>                
    <iterate>
       <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
          <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" 
                value="*.h"/>
       </adapt>
    </iterate>
</visibleWhen>
```